# git pull over ssh gives errors

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

This is my setup.

1. My git repository is in bitbucket
2. I have created keys on my remote aws ec2 server and kept it in **~/.ssh** folder
3. I then add the key via the ssh-agent on my remote server
4. Updated these keys on the bitbucket website.

When I login to my remote server and run "git pull" on my git repository everything works fine. **No issues here.**

But when I run the same the same via the cygwin bash on windows it gives me this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I do the following on my windows machine

```
ssh -i xyz.pem user@ip -t 'sudo sh deploy.sh'
```

Where the "deploy.sh", **cd's** into my repository and does a `git pull`.

Why is this issue happening ? **Should I also keep these ssh keys on my windows machine?**
Any help will be invaluable.

Comment: If you (EC2) and your spouse (Win) want to enter your house (the BitBucket repo), who of you will need a key to it? You can have a different pair of public/private keys on your Windows machine, though, as long as you deposit the public key at BitBucket, too.

Comment: But I "ssh" into my remote machine. Should it not take the creds that i stored on my ec2 linux machine?

Comment: I created keys on windows machine and added the public key to bitbucket. Still this issue does not get fixed!

Comment: OK, I got that mixed up. You want to SSH from your Windows machine to your EC2 instance. Then you still need a pair of keys on the Windows machine and the public key as one line of `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the _EC2 instance_. Bitbucket is completely out of the game here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using **"sudo"** in 'sudo sh deploy.sh' which prompted it to check the creds in root users .ssh folder. Remove the "sudo" and it works fine.

Comment: Cant do it for the next 2 days @jimmycarr